# Redirect to previous page from servlet filter in web application

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, forward, referrer

I have been going through several links to understand how we can redirect to the previous page from filter.

**What I am trying to do**

There is one `A.jsp`. On click of submit, it goes to one of the filter which checks something and if there is an issue, it sends it back to `A.jsp`.

**Solutions I tried**

1. I can not use `request.getHeader("referrer")` because URL changes when I submit the page. So It will work for first time but will fail after that.
2. Add hidden input in every jsp which will be sent as a request paramter and we can use that in filter to send it back. This can work but It will require changes in every jsp page which i dont want due to the large count of jsps.

Is there anything which I am missing?

Any standard way to handle this case?

Comment: Please add code for A.jsp, and your filter, thanks

Comment: @jr593: Did you read the question? Your comment seems an unthoughtful knee-jerk one which one would likely post on every single question without a block of code. I'm not seeing how exactly the requested information would help in answering the question in its current form. It would only add more irrelevant clutter to the question making it yet less attractive to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better options, but in the absence of other answers, you could add the hidden input automatically to each form with javascript. If you have any jsp-includes for content shared among your pages, you could add a script tag with a function that looks something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)
    {
        var form = document.forms[i];
        (function(form){
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                var element = document.createElement('input');
                element.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                element.setAttribute('name', 'returnpage');
                element.setAttribute('value', window.location);
                form.appendChild(element);
            });                        
        })(form);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is more or less similar to using request.getHeader("referer") which is dependent on url.